# How to setState inside an api function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-class-based-component

I have this code inside a class method:

```
ref
      .orderByValue()
      .equalTo(email)
      .once("value", snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          console.log(this);
          this.setState({ signedUp: true });
        } else {
          ref.update({ [newKey]: email });
        }
      });
```

It's going to update my Firebase database on submit, unless the user has already signed up. A typeError says `this.setState is not a function`. But when I console log `this`, the console prints out the class. Logging `this.state` also prints out the state.

How do I fix this? I want to update my state from inside this function.

Comment: add the full code of the class

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use functional component.

However if you want to use class component, this is probably a binding issue.

So if this is triggered inside function named `func`, you should bind this function inside the constructor.

```
...
constructor(props) {
...
this.func = this.func.bind(this);
...
}
func() {
...
ref
      .orderByValue()
      .equalTo(email)
      .once("value", snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          console.log(this);
          this.setState({ signedUp: true });
        } else {
          ref.update({ [newKey]: email });
        }
      });
...
}
```

If you don't want to bind this function, you should use arrow function.

```
func = () => {
...
}
```

Comment: self=this workaround is for es5. It won’t help with arrows.